# SQL query to find count of visits within date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query below works in just about all aspects except it returns the total count of encounters (pe.enc_id) ever. I'm trying to find the total count of visits just in 2016.

```
select distinct p.person_nbr, p.last_name, p.first_name, p.race, count(pe.enc_id) as count_of_encounters 
from patient_encounter pe
    inner join person p on pe.person_id = p.person_id
    inner join patient_diagnosis pd on pd.enc_id = pe.enc_id
WHERE (p.date_of_birth between '19420101' and '19981231' and pe.enc_timestamp >= '20160101' AND pe.enc_timestamp  < '20170101')
    and pd.person_id in (select distinct p.person_id from person p  inner join patient_diagnosis pd on p.person_id = pd.person_id
where (pd.diagnosis_code_id  like '250%' or pd.diagnosis_code_id like '648.0%' 
    or pd.diagnosis_code_id  like '357.2' or pd.diagnosis_code_id like '362.0[0-7]' or pd.diagnosis_code_id  like '366.41' or pd.diagnosis_code_id like 'E1[0-3].%' 
    or pd.diagnosis_code_id  like 'O24.[0-4]0%' or pd.diagnosis_code_id like 'O24.[4-9][2-9]') )
group by p.person_nbr, p.last_name, p.first_name, p.race
having count(pe.enc_id) >= 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query sure looks like it is filtering on the date.  I do have some suggestions:

- You have no need for `select distinct`
- Your subquery is overly complicated.
- In fact, I don't think it is necessary.

You appear to be looking for patients that have a particular diagnosis, and then counting the number of diagnoses.  You can do this all in the outer aggregation, by extending the `having` clause:

So:

```
select p.person_nbr, p.last_name, p.first_name, p.race,
       count(pe.enc_id) as count_of_encounters 
from patient_encounter pe inner join
     person p
     on pe.person_id = p.person_id inner join
     patient_diagnosis pd
     on pd.enc_id = pe.enc_id
where p.date_of_birth between '19420101' and '19981231' and
      pe.enc_timestamp >= '20160101' AND pe.enc_timestamp  < '20170101') 
group by p.person_nbr, p.last_name, p.first_name, p.race
having count(pe.enc_id) >= 2 and
       sum(case when pd.diagnosis_code_id  like '250%' or pd.diagnosis_code_id like '648.0%' 
    or pd.diagnosis_code_id  like '357.2' or pd.diagnosis_code_id like '362.0[0-7]' or pd.diagnosis_code_id  like '366.41' or pd.diagnosis_code_id like 'E1[0-3].%' 
    or pd.diagnosis_code_id  like 'O24.[0-4]0%' or pd.diagnosis_code_id like 'O24.[4-9][2-9]' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```